# Debug message shows twice from an Adapter

Tags: c#, android, listview, debugging, adapter

I put a `Console.WriteLine()` in `GetView()` method of a custom adapter, like so: (Please note the code is in c# and I cant use the duplicate answer because I cant inherit from an abstact method in c#)

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(myContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ExerciseRowBig, null, false);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Hello");

        return row;
    }
```

And the problem is that the debugger shows the message "Hello" twice, even though there is only one item in the ListView. Why? Is it intended?

Comment: Please print `Environment.StackTrace` to the console too and post the results.

Comment: I found out why according to this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230155/android-getview-called-twice-in-custom-adapter

Comment: I just dont know how to implement it in c# becase `base.GetView()` is abstract.

Comment: `StackTrace` doesnt exist in Environment for me

Comment: Please help me migrating the code to c#

Comment: "I just dont know how to implement it in c#" - Implement what, exactly? That's just how `Adapter`s work. There is no guarantee as to how many times or in which order `GetView()` will be called. You shouldn't have any logic there that relies on those things.